# Have MSDN Ultimate 7 installed by company. Want to convert to personal Ultimate 7. Can I?

Tags: windows-7, windows, upgrade, msdn

I purchased a used development PC with Ultimate 7 MSDN version on it.  I own a laptop with Ultimate 7 full, installed over XP.  I also own a 3 user Home 7 with only one install (2 left).  Yes, it's messy.  I also own unused copies of XP (2 or 3, not new, but not installed on anything at this time).

So, I think I'm legal to buy an Ultimate 7 Upgrade, or an Ultimate 7 Anytime Upgrade!

The Anytime Upgrade is cheapest!

Can I purchase an Anytime 7 Upgrade, and just enter the new key to turn the MSDN into a personal Ultimate 7?

Gee, I hope you can follow that!

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't really follow :S

If you purchased a used development machine with a MSDN version of Windows 7, it is **ONLY** licensed for development and testing usage. It should of been deleted/formatted before you purchased.

If you have a full copy of Windows 7 Home, you can then purchase a Windows 7 Anytime Upgrade package, although depending on your usage, if you are going to be using this machine for some time, you may want to consider all out buying a Windows 7 Ultimate OEM edition. Depending on pricing in your area.

As for the upgrade, no you can't. Windows does not know it is a MSDN copy, it thinks it is a regular full retail copy however by the license terms, it should not be running. You can not upgrade a Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 7 Ultimate.

You can however change the product key to another full retail edition, but I would not recommend this due to price.

Comment: When I'm working, I have MSDN access.  But, I didn't buy it from my employer, and I'm not using it for development!  It would be illegal for me to use it at home.  That is why I want to 'convert' it to a 'legal' key.  And, I helped set it up in the first place, so it benefits me to keep it 'as is' if I can.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Ultimate 7 is the same whether you got it from a MSDN license or personally purchased it yourself.  There's no need to "upgrade" the MSDN version.

Comment: Technically (and legally) it should be deleted and removed, but if they were to acquire a valid key, I am sure no fuss would be made.

Comment: @Wil agreed, but assuming that you have legal access to a MSDN there's not need.  However, this doesn't not seem to be the case.

Comment: -1 The licensing terms are different.  Even the user who possesses an MSDN subscription still will need a separate license for home (non-developer) use.